# MySQL Selecting Dynamic Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

I have a `datetime` column and I want to select all rows from the previous 2 complete months (Sept and Oct, currently). Manually I could compose this query as:

```
where date_column between '2018-09-01' and '2018-10-31'
```

but how can I do this programmatically so the end date is always correct? I was thinking

```
where date_column between concat(substr(now() - INTERVAL 2 month, 1, 7), '-01') and concat(substr(now() - INTERVAL 1 month, 1, 7), '-31')
```

but the `31` will be incorrect for November, February, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could format the date and just hard code the day to be 1:

```
date_column BETWEEN
            DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AND
            DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: Oh, so for the second value (the most recent current month) it would be `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01')` and that will function as . `00:00:00` for the time value, or would that pass as `23:59:59`?

Comment: @user3783243 actually, `between` has the semantics of value >= start and value < end. If you use the **current** month (see my edit that removed the interval) with day=1 and no referene to the time, you'll get a condition of "dates before the starting moment of THIS month" - which means everything in the past month.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So my `and '2018-10-31'` was actually cutting out 1 day of valid data.

Comment: @user3783243 yup

Comment: Um, that's not quite right: `SELECT 4 BETWEEN 1 AND 4 -> 1`

Comment: Actually, yes @Strawberry Is right, I need to add `and date_column <> DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01')` to remove the high range, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1548c5/3 vs http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1548c5/2